# Interpolating binned data such that bin average is preserved

Tags: algorithms, interpolation, binning

Say I have this binned data as input. The average value $\bar{y}_i$ is given for each successive $\Delta x_i$ interval. For simplicity, let's assume sampling density is uniform within each bin.

Now I want to estimate the underlying function $y$($x$) i.e. I want to be able to get reasonable estimates of $y$ for arbitrary, punctual values of $x$ (e.g. $x$ = 2.3 or 2.5 or whatever).   The requirement are:

1. The function must preserve the average over each bin, $\overline{y(x)}_i = \bar{y}_i$, so as to not introduce bias
2. The function must be continuous (i.e. no discontinuities)
3. The function must be non-negative. (Negative values are unphysical.)

Simply looking up the bin value for a given $x$ would satisfy #1, but violate #2 (there are discontinuities at all bin edges).

On the other hand, assigning the entire bin weight to each bin center, and then interpolating between those points, satisfies #2, but violates #1 (regardless of whether it's linear or higher-order spline interpolation). In the illustration below, the 2<$x$<3 bin average is not preserved; it is reduced, as both corners get cut downward.

How can this be done in a way that satisfies both requirements?

Also, what is this operation called? Is this interpolation? (Not sure how to tag this question.)

[image]

Comment: This question is also related to [this question here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59418/interpolation-of-influenza-data-that-conserves-weekly-mean/).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a paper that describes an iterative method that does what you're asking:

> **Mean preserving algorithm for smoothly interpolating averaged data**
>
> M.D. Rymes, D.R. Myers, Mean preserving algorithm for smoothly
>   interpolating averaged data, Solar Energy, Volume 71, Issue 4, 2001,
>   Pages 225-231, ISSN 0038-092X,
>   https://doi.org/10.1016/S0038-092X(01)00052-4.
>   (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0038092X01000524)
>
> Abstract: Hourly mean or monthly mean values of measured solar
>   radiation are typical vehicles for summarized solar radiation and
>   meteorological data. Often, solar-based renewable energy system
>   designers, researchers, and engineers prefer to work with more highly
>   time resolved data, such as detailed diurnal profiles, or mean daily
>   values. The object of this paper is to present a simple method for
>   smoothly interpolating averaged (coarsely resolved) data into data
>   with a finer resolution, while preserving the deterministic mean of
>   the data. The technique preserves the proper component relationship
>   between direct, diffuse, and global solar radiation (when values for
>   at least two of the components are available), as well as the
>   deterministic mean of the coarsely resolved data. Examples based on
>   measured data from several sources and examples of the applicability
>   of this mean preserving smooth interpolator to other averaged data,
>   such as weather data, are presented.

Comment: This does sound like a solution. Too bad it's behind a paywall.

Comment: You'll find a downloadable copy with your favorite search engine;  I got it yesterday.

Comment: Is there an implementation of the algorithm for R?

Answer (score 3):

Mean preserving or average preserving splines can be generated from "normal" interpolating splines. Your requirements:

- $\frac{1}{x_{i+1}-x_i} \int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} f(x) \text{d}x = \text{avg}_i$
- $f\in\text{C}^1$, or at least $f\in\text{C}^0$
- $f(x)\geq 0$

can be written equivalently by defining the integral
$F(x) = \int_{x_0}^x f(t) \text{d}t$:

- $F(x_{i+1}) = F(x_i) + \text{avg}_i \, (x_{i+1}-x_i)$
- $F\in\text{C}^2$, or at least $F\in\text{C}^1$
- $F(x)$ is monotonic

This is now a standard spline interpolation for $F$. In R you could do something like:

```
avg = c(2.2, 3.5, 5.5, 4.5, 2.2, 0.2, 4.5)
X=0:length(avg)

Y=vector(length=length(X))
Y[0]=0
for(i in 2:length(Y)) Y[i]=Y[i-1]+avg[i-1]*(X[i]-X[i-1])

#s=splinefun(X,Y,method="natural")
#s=splinefun(X,Y,method="monoH.FC")
s=splinefun(X,Y,method="hyman")

Xplot=seq(X[1],tail(X,n=1),by=0.02)
Yplot=s(Xplot,deriv=1)

barplot(avg, space=0,ylim=c(-0.5,6))
lines(Xplot,Yplot)
```

result for `s=splinefun(X,Y,method="natural")` (not guaranteed positive)
[image: spline with method="natural"]

result for `s=splinefun(X,Y,method="monoH.FC")`
[image: spline with method="monoH.FC"]

result for `s=splinefun(X,Y,method="hyman")`
[image: spline with method="hyman"]

Comment: For an implementation in C++ see https://kluge.in-chemnitz.de/opensource/spline/#mean_preserv (disclosure: I'm the author)

Comment: the C++ implementation looks amazing. Since I have only used C++ throughout Rcpp, I would like to ask if you believe these C++ functions could by used throughout Rcpp?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've got so far is to do a linear interpolation between points at bin centers as shown in the graph in the question, after having done a numerical optimisation of all the $y_i$, iterating until condition #1 is met (and with a harsh penalty for violating #3). Unfortunately, numerical optimisation is a bit of a heavier process than I had hoped for.

Instead of doing numerical optimisation, I tried just setting up and solving a set of linear equations. That is really straightforward and quick, but it is not robust against requirement #3: some of the $y_i$ can end up negative, which is nonsensical. Unfortunately, #3 is a non-linear thing and can't be incorporated in the set of linear equations, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Could you provide any further details about the method you describe "setting up and solving a set of linear equations"? The algorithm described above works well, but it is computationally expensive, requiring at least as many iterations as interpolated timesteps. For a problem not requiring condition #3, is there a way to achieve a means-preserving interpolation that is more efficient than Rymes and Myers (2001)?

Comment: For _n_ points your function has 2n - 2 parameters (n-1) of ax+b segments. Req #1 provides n equations, and req #2: n-1, total 2n-1. This is overconstrained. Unless you add two more segments covering the extreme halves of the first and the last bins, then you have 2n+2 parameters and 2n-1 equations. Only 3 free parameters. How do you find them? How do you prevent the function from oscillating?

Answer (score -4):

Binning is highly discouraged because of inefficiency, discontinuity, and arbitrariness.  But you have made the implicit assumption that the bins should be non-overlapping.  Making the bins overlap and having many more of them will alleviate some of the problems although regression splines are better.

Don't use bin centers to represent the distribution of $x$ within the bin.  Use the mean $x$ within each bin.

Comment: I'm not advocating for or against the use of bins, nor for/against having them overlap. I'm saying, this is the data I have to work with. It's my input. I don't have any higher-grade source of information, unfortunately. Also, given the stated simplifying assumption that samples are uniformly distributed within bins, mean *x* will be the same as bin center.